# Python kopf operator throwing ssl certificate error

Tags: python, kubernetes, ssl, certificate

When i try to deploy my operator on k8 cluster, it’s throwing error like ssl certificate like

> clientconnectorcertificateerror(connectionkey(host='10.xxxxxx',
> port=443, is_ssl=true, ssl=none, proxy=none, proxy_auth=none,
> proxy_headers_hash=xxxxxxxxxx), sslcertverificationerror(1, '[ssl:
> certificate_verify_failed] certificate verify failed: unable to get
> issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)'))

Basically it’s trying to do GET request to kubernetes api and hitting with this error !!
Should I need to configure anything on kopf ?

When I tried to deploy this operator on minikube it was working, but when it is deployed in k8’s cluster it throwing ssl certificate error actually it is trying to do GET request to kubernets api but not able connect with kubernetes api